# MYSQL stored procedure not checking the where clause and returning entire table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Viewuser`(IN `userID` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM  `tbl_userdetails` WHERE `UserID`=userID;
END
```

In the above code the user details of given user id should be return. But it returning the entire table while i execute this stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. The field name in table should not be same as variable name.. That is the problem

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `Viewuser`(IN `ID` VARCHAR(50))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM  `tbl_userdetails` WHERE `UserID`=ID;
END

This is working fine

Answer (score 0):

try this method:

```
mysql> delimiter //

mysql> CREATE PROCEDURE simpleproc (OUT param1 INT)
    -> BEGIN
    ->   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t;
    -> END//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> delimiter ;

mysql> CALL simpleproc(@a);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT @a;
+------+
| @a   |
+------+
| 3    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

***https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html***

Comment: Thanks for your response. But now also it is returning the entire table. I'm executing in phpmyadmin.

Comment: you should remove the `In` and try